# How to split spark DataFrame into numpy arrays to use them as tensorflow's convolutional neural network inputs?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pyspark, conv-neural-network

I have a spark DataFrame "A" that looks like:

```
   customer         A         B         C
0         1  0.999471  0.746963  0.098438
1         1  0.986164  0.762772  0.715350
2         1  0.656797  0.975615  0.002074
3         2  0.892825  0.542348  0.648907
4         2  0.806137  0.806392  0.365054
5         2  0.707369  0.535159  0.205938
6         3  0.072516  0.381937  0.076068
7         3  0.442076  0.634749  0.918520
8         3  0.628006  0.842492  0.971928
```

I want to split the dataframe into 3 height, 3 width, 1 depth numpy arrays (similar to images) by customer to use them as inputs for a tensorflow's convolutional neural network. For example for *customer 1* the desired np.array with shape (3, 3, 1) would look like:

```
array([[[0.99947138],
        [0.74696311],
        [0.09843827]],

       [[0.98616396],
        [0.7627723 ],
        [0.71534965]],

       [[0.65679665],
        [0.97561509],
        [0.00207389]]])
```

So far I have the following code (which I guess is not efficient, as it takes nearly 10 seconds to generate each image for the amount of data I'm handling)

```
customers = [1,2,3]
images = []
for customer in customers:
    img = A.filter(col("customer") == customer).select("A", "B", "C").toPandas().values.reshape(3,3,1)
    images.append(img)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

**Note:** After that I convert the list *images* to a numpy array to input it to the CNN network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perform main calculation on dataframe like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv('data/d.csv').select("customer",col("A").cast("float"),col("B").cast("float"),col("C").cast("float"))
df.show()

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|customer|       A|       B|       C|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1|0.999471|0.746963|0.098438|
|       1|0.986164|0.762772| 0.71535|
|       1|0.656797|0.975615|0.002074|
|       2|0.892825|0.542348|0.648907|
|       2|0.806137|0.806392|0.365054|
|       2|0.707369|0.535159|0.205938|
|       3|0.072516|0.381937|0.076068|
|       3|0.442076|0.634749| 0.91852|
|       3|0.628006|0.842492|0.971928|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Using spark function `collect_list` you can get data for each customer.

```
df2 = np.array(df.groupBy("customer").agg(collect_list(array(array("A"), array("B"), array("C")))).collect())
# select data from customer = 1
images = np.asarray([x[1] for x in df2 if x[0] == '1' ])
print images
```

output:

```
[[[[0.99947101]
   [0.74696302]
   [0.098438  ]]

  [[0.98616397]
   [0.76277202]
   [0.71534997]]

  [[0.65679699]
   [0.97561502]
   [0.002074  ]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Which libraries are you using for CNN? If you are using standard libraries such as keras or pytorch, then to_Pandas() or collect() is the only way. Both may cause issues when data size is large. There are many distributed deep learning packages that provide native dataframe support, so you can run your model directly. Check the resources here :

https://joerihermans.com/work/distributed-keras/

https://towardsdatascience.com/distributed-deep-learning-pipelines-with-pyspark-and-keras-a3a1c22b9239

Using these will be the best way to go.

Comment: I am using keras only. Previously tried with a the *BigDL* library but for security reasons the installation of the library won't happen in the near future.